Spacing and indexing in quantikz
Can somebody explain how I can add space in the following picture and code?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{quantikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{A} &&& \\
\lstick[2]{\ket{\Phi^+}}\lstick{B} &&& \\
\lstick{C} &&& \\
\lstick{$A_1$} &&&
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}


Sorry, but I don't see code, I see only some JPEGs. A screenshot is usually better than nothing, but it it not useful for copy&paste and therefore for reproducing a problem and searching for improvements.

@cabohah I have edited the question putting the MWE.

\lstick puts the argument to the left of the column, so the two \lsticks each put their content to the left of the same horizontal point, causing them to overlap.
Instead, use an extra column and disable the wire.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
& \lstick{A} \wireoverride{n} &&& \\
\lstick[2]{\ket{\Phi^{+}}} & \lstick{B} \wireoverride{n} &&& \\
& \lstick{C} \wireoverride{n} &&& \\
& \lstick{D} \wireoverride{n} &&& \\
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}



Using \midstick seems to do the trick
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{quantikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
                             \midstick{A}     &&&& \\ 
  \lstick[2]{\ket{\Phi^+}}   \midstick{B}     &&&& \\
                             \midstick{C}     &&&& \\
                             \midstick{$A_1$} &&&&   
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}



+1. This generates a little more space from the braces than my answer (https://i.sstatic.net/XIR8Pzwc.png) but is easier to write, without needing to switch off the wires.

@DaiBowen totally agree, yours looks nicer
